# Unable to build Card.io with existing OpenCV framework

Tags: c++, ios, opencv, card.io, cardio

I'm building an app that already uses the iOS OpenCV 2 framework to perform some image processing. When I add the Card.io iOS SDK I get a load of build errors that look like clashes with its own OpenCV implementation. If I remove the original OpenCV framework the app builds fine but none of the image processing code works.

Any thoughts on how I can get this building and running?

[image: screen shot 2015-10-06 at 15 51 10]